# Why does BIDE use the semi-maximum period for search space pruning?

Tags: algorithm, data-mining

According to the article which defines BIDE:

> [BIDE: Efficient Mining of Frequent Closed Sequences](http://hanj.cs.illinois.edu/pdf/tkde07_wangj.pdf)
>
> Theorem 2 (BackScan search space pruning):
>
> Let the prefix sequence be an
> n-sequence, `Sp=e1e2...en`. If `∃i(1≤i≤n)` and there exists an item `e′`
> which appears in each of the i-th semi-maximum periods of the prefix
> `Sp` in `SDB`, we can safely stop growing prefix `Sp`.
>
> Proof:
>
> Because item `e′`
> appears in each of the i-th semi-maximum periods of the prefix `Sp` in
> `SDB`, we can get a new prefix `S′p=e1e2...ei−1e′ei...en` `(1<i≤n)` or
> `S′p=e′e1e2...en(i=1)`, and both `(Sp ‎⊂ S′p)` and
> `(supSDB(Sp)=supSDB(S′p))` hold. Any locally frequent item `e′′` w.r.t.
> prefix `Sp` is also a locally frequent item w.r.t. `S′p`, in the meantime
> `(〈Sp,e′′〉⊂〈S′p,e′′〉)` and `(supSDB(〈Sp,e′′〉)=supSDB(〈S′p,e′′〉))` hold.
> This means there is no hope to mine frequent closed sequences with
> prefix `Sp`.

I understand that for example if I have an `AB` pattern, and I find an `e'`, for example `C`, which is in the 2nd maximum period of the pattern, so between `A` and `B` for every sequence, which contains `AB`, then I can stop growing `AB`, because I could use backward extension to make `ACB`, which will have the same support, but it is longer. So any pattern I would get by extending `AB` forward, certainly won't be a closed pattern, because the `C` is missing from it. That's why I have to stop growing `AB` and wait until PrefixSpan grows `A -> AC -> ACB` with forward extension.

What I don't understand is why the maximum period must be constrained to the semi-maximum period in this context and why testing for the semi-maximum period is okay.

The article does not write a real explanation. Any idea? Can you write an example where we lose closed frequent patterns by using the maximum period instead of the semi-maximum period?

Comment: The question is about a sequential pattern mining algorithm. I wonder why it was closed, though not the first time people don't even understanding basic concepts vote on close here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the answer. Here is an example which has new events in the max period, but not in the semi-max period:

```
[AxByB,AqBtyB], AB
2nd max period: [xBy,qBty] -> By
2nd semi-max period: [x,q] -> 0
```

According to it, I cannot stop growing `AB`, because there is no `e'` in the semi-max period with the same support. On the other hand there is `e'` in the max period with the same support, so  we could reach `A{By}B` pattern with backward extension from `AB`.

But I found that we can reach `AB{yB}` with forward extension from `AB` too. With more overlaps, for example by patterns like `ABAB` we will get the same conclusion; we can grow the initial `AB` with forward extension into `AB{*A*B}`, but we cannot add any character to the semi max period `A{*}B`, because we cannot reach that with forward extension from `AB` and PrefixSpan grows pattern with forward extension only.

So for example if we find `x` in the 2nd semi max period of `AB` with the same support, then we have to stop growing `AB` and wait for PrefixSpan to grow `AxB` in the `A -> Ax -> AxB` way, and continue to grow the `AxB` pattern rather than the `AB` pattern. Of course, we are looking for closed frequent patterns here, not for frequent patterns, so we can prune the search space this way safely.

I am not sure whether it is possible to design a frequent pattern mining algorithm, which does both forward and backward extensions. Maybe later I'll try to design such an algorithm just for the challenge, but for now BIDE is fine for what I am doing.